# Reconnecting in Socket.io and maintaining client id?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Is this possible? I can't find any documentation on the subject but from the tests I've done so far, a new client id is assigned every time a client reconnects.
If its not possible what would be the best workaround?
Thanks!

Comment: the workaround is to use session state.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the moment I don't think it's possible (I've asked the same question myself to `3rd-Eden, Socket.IO core dev).

However you can setup some unique key yourself on the client's session, that's the best workaround at the moment and usually people find this ok (for example put the username on the session or another unique id).

Comment: Thanks once again for the fast reply :) I've now implemented something like that. When the user connects I'm creating a HMAC token (using crypto) with their client id and then sending it to them. If the user reconnects they send back their assigned token where I then authenticate them on the server and assign them back their original user info and associate it with their new client id

Comment: It would be nice if you can update your post with the example, I'm sure others will find that very useful. Thanks